# Submitting two values using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want submit/post two values with this jQuery code:

```
$('input#code1').on('input', function(){
  var name = $('input#code1').val();
  if ($.trim(name) != ''){
    $.post('ajax/rate1.php', {code1: name}, function(data){
      $('div#total1').text(data);
    });
  }
});
```

How can I also include an additional value (qty1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have qty in `$('input#code2')` just retrive the value and add to javascript object for post

```
    var name = $('input#code1').val();    
    var qty = $('input#code2').val();

    if ($.trim(name) != ''){
        $.post('ajax/rate1.php', {code1: name, code2, qty}, function(data){
        $('div#total1').text(data);
        });
   }
```

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge, everything worked the way I expected! :D

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) accepts a data object, which can contain multiple values.

> **data**
>   Type: PlainObject or String
>   A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

For example:

```js
var parameters = {
  "name" : $('input#code1').val(),
  "qty"  : $('input#qty1').val()
};

$.post('ajax/rate1.php', parameters, function(data){
  $('div#total1').text(data);
});
```

Then, in PHP:

```
$name = !empty($_POST['name']) && !ctype_space($_POST['name'])
          ? trim($_POST['name'])
          : '(unnamed)';

$qty = !empty($_POST['qty']) && is_numeric($_POST['qty'])
          ? $_POST['qty']
          : 0;
```

---

For reference, see the [examples in the jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#entry-examples):

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  }
);
```